# How to execute inodbcluster status using bash shell script

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, innodb, router, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am working on the MySQL InnoDB cluster, I have a requirement to execute cluster status using shell script.

```
MySQL  db:3306 ssl  JS > dba.getCluster().status()
```

Is there any way that I can execute the above command using the bash shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [command line integration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/command-line-integration-overview.html) for that purpose.

Quick example:

```
$ mysqlsh root@db:3306 -- cluster status
```